# Making a variable out of another variables' value in php (php basics)

Tags: php

I need to make a dynamic variable based on a loop, what i am looking for is a variable something like

> $var = "foo";
>
> $$var = "bar";
>
> echo $foo; // bar

but for me it should be more like a fixed parameter attached to the dynamic part like

> $var='123';
>
> $'current_'.$$var=some value; // not correct syntax
>
> echo $current_123 should give 'some value';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use curly braces:

```
$${'current_' . $var} = $some_value;
```

Comment: That is the recommended way.. but variable variables are nasty if you're not careful. They're harder to read, trace, and debug. If you *must* use them, please document it for the next guy.