# PHP make variable value part of another variable name

Tags: php, variables, variable-assignment, dynamic-variables

I am trying to create a new variable out of part of another variables value.  I have gone through multiple other SO threads but I am trying to figure out how to make the new variable its own instance.  [Making a variable out of another variables' value in php (php basics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516464/making-a-variable-out-of-another-variables-value-in-php-php-basics)

I have this variable: `$id = 0 ;`

I want to create: `$limit_$id (IE: $limit_0)` that I can reference just as native variable.  I believe I can do this: `$${'limit_'.$id}`, but is there any way to actually end up with `$limit_0` so I don't have to reference it as `$${'limit_'.$id)` ???

Comment: This is a bit of a code smell. You're likely better off just using an array, like `$limit[$id]`.

Comment: @rolinger The request seems to make no sense: if you already know the final name of the variable, you don't need to compose it with other variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "reference it as `$${'limit_'.$id)`"?

You can do something like:

```php
$id = 0;

${'limit_' . $id} = 'foo';

echo $limit_0; // foo
```

But, as someone already pointed out in a comment: if you already know the name of the final variable, you can just define it directly with that name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the form `${"limit_$id"}`, but it's a variation of what you already proposed:

```php
<?php
$id = 1;
$limit_1 = 42;
echo ${"limit_$id"}, PHP_EOL;
${"limit_$id"} = 43;
echo ${"limit_$id"}, PHP_EOL;
```